# Counting problem of combinations of symmetric matrix.

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, combinations, integer-partitions, computational-mathematics

Given, a symmetric $n*n$ matrix $G$ with 0,1 entries. Each row of has same number of 1.  $G$ is arranged in a certain order using a rule. The rule is described below-
 $G$ is partitioned in to two sub matrices  based on the adjacency of $n$ th column/row(column=row since it is a symmetric matrix).

e.g. n=10 for below matrix,10th  vertex  partitioned  the whole matrix into 2 parts(matrices ),

[image]

Vertices which are adjacent to  10th vertex(7,8,9 in one part) and vertices which are not (1,2,3,4,5,6 in other part ).
[image]

After repetition, the final picture would be,

[image]

**Question:** If $H$ is a permuted $G$, (i.e. $H=P G$ ,where P is a permutation matrix), following the given rule, how many combinations require to check(minimum number) to ensure that H is a permuted G?
 i.e if $H$ is not a permuted $G$,how many combinations require to check(minimum number) to ensure that H is not a permuted G?

Comment: suggest trying to describe your problem completely/ rigorously _without_ examples 1st.... and then clearly showing how the _examples_ fit the math operations....

Comment: I'm not sure this is as completely described as you think. What do you mean by "$G$ is partitioned in to two sub matrices based on the **adjacency** of $n$ th column/row". How do you determine which cols/rows are _adjacent_ to the $n$th col/row? Note, too, that if $H=PG$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix, then $H$ is obtained by just permuting the _rows_ of $G$, so may not be symmetric itself. Does this matter? After partitioning $G$ do you permute something?

Comment: Also, some motivation for this may be in order. Is this just an interesting something that you thought of? Do you have some application in mind?