# Reorder adjacency matrices of regular graphs so they are the same

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-isomorphism, adjacency-matrix

Given a matrix A of a strongly $k$ regular graph G(srg($n,k,\lambda,\mu$);$\lambda ,\mu >0;k>3$). The matrix A can be divided into 4 sub matrices  based on adjacency of vertex $x \in G$.
 $A_x$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph $(G-x)$, where $C$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph created by  vertices of $(G-x)$ which are  not adjacent to $x$ and $D$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph created by  vertices of $(G-x)$ which are  adjacent to $x$.

$$ A_x = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc|ccc|c}
0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
\hline
1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
C & E & 0 \\
E^{T} & D & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array} \right) 
$$

It should be noted that

1. Interchanging/swapping any two rows (or columns) of $C$ does not affect matrix $D$ (and vice versa).
2. Any change in $C$ or $D$ or both $C$ and $D$ changes matrix $E$.

**Problem:**  If some vertices of $G$ is rearranged (i.e., permuted), $A$  will be different, say, ***this new matrix is $B$. Again, matrix $B$ can be divided into 4 sub matrices  based on adjacency of vertex $x \in G$ and $ B_x$ can be obtained.***

Assume:

1. $C$ is always the adjacency matrix of a regular graph and bigger than $D$.
2. There exists an algorithm that always order $D$ (for a vertex $x \in G$) takes $O(K)$ time (assumed to be polynomial/exponential, does not matter).
3. Each row of E has different permutation, i.e., rows might have same number of 1's but different permutation/arrangement  of 1.

   For $n$ vertices there will be total $n$ numbers of $C,D$, each of them will take $O(K)$ (assumed to be polynomial) time to sort. If each $C$ takes time $O(f(n))$ to sort, then the total complexity will be $O(n \cdot K \cdot f(n))$.

**Question:** According to the three assumptions above, does there exist a polynomial time algorithm to sort $C$ so that $B=A$? I.e., is there a polynomial $f$ ?

The problem is connected to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240637/counting-problem-of-combinations-of-symmetric-matrix).

***If anything is unclear, please ask a specific question, I will try my best to answer.***

Comment: I think you are asking to solve [(sub)graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). For general graphs, we don't know a polynomial-time algorithm for either. That does not preclude better algorithms for your restricted class; I recommend a literature search with "(sub)graph isomorphism" and "regular graphs".

Comment: It seems that Daniel Spielman's paper [*Faster Isomorphism Testing for Strongly Regular Graphs*](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/Research/grisom.html) (STOC 1996) is a good place to start looking. At least in 1996, testing isomorphism of strongly regular graphs wasn't known to be in **P** or to be as hard as the isomorphism problem for general graphs.

Comment: Dear Sirs, thanks for your feedback, but you are talking about the general case(I am aware of Spielman). What I have posted here (according to 3 assumption above),is a little bit different. If I am not wrong, it is possible to have a better complexity than what Spielman , please check the new edition, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: this is impressive but the _question_ is buried. you seem to want to rearrange k-regular graphs in some way to do... _x._ what is _x_? you seem mainly to want an efficient algorithm for _x_. it would help by attempting to boil down _x_ within existing algorithmic operations/ studies. there are many studies of regular graphs. is this mainly a graph isomorphism question? you seem to have strong mathematical background yet unfamiliar with graph isomorphisms (& other basic graph operations etc)... looking over the [math.se] question, even that is not very clear. try starting over & also [chat]

Comment: @Jim just write something (as much as possible) in [chat] & generally have to do it asynchronously, it has chat reply mechanisms for signalling; there is already some brief discussion of your problem(s)/ migration etc by mod R & others

Comment: some further thought/ analysis on this with jim in chat room. while this question shows some significant analysis, have suspicion jim has taken single regular graph instance & partitioned it into matrices/ structure & while insinuating it in the question, after request doesnt seem to have any proof/ response this can be done in general (with all regular graphs) & hes not disabusing me of this notion so far. its clearly the basis for the whole question, but lacking a proof, am presuming it is likely not true in general. also motivation seems to be study of hard graphs for graph isomorphism.

Comment: also, now wondering, is this actually a veiled question of (aiming in the direction) whether graph isomorphism is in P? which is open?

Comment: " jim has taken single regular graph instance & partitioned it into matrices/ structure " no , i  said earlier, saying it again , that example is just an illustration of the idea.  I could be wrong but I am 100% sure you have not  read my solution properly, please read and ask a specific question. lets find out where I went wrong.

Comment: Two questions: How is the matrix E created?  What definition of permutation are you using?  If two strings equal length strings consisting of zeroes and ones only have the same number of ones in them, then the strings are permutable to each other under the definition of permutation I'm familiar with.

Comment: @KyleJones, I don't understand your question, $E$ is a part of the adjacency matrix, we look at it according to the situation described above. you need to consider how permutation is applied in matrix.for example, if you have a matrix where 1st 3 rows are exactly same then it does not matter what permutation you apply, they will remain same(those 3 rows will look same, no difference between them ), with different permutation, it would not happen. this is true regarding matrices like E , permutation of symmetric matrix is different.

Comment: This question was [migrated from Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19790). I am remigrating to [math.se] at the asker's request.

Answer (score 1):

this will not be a *direct* answer at what does not really seem a *direct* question, which in its apparently big scope/ ambition pushes outside the bounds of SE questions but is nevertheless aimed to be a scientific and guiding response. you seem to be studying [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) in general, and as you are apparently aware the precise complexity of this is a major open problem. and it is known/ utilized generally that regular graphs are the "hard" ones for GI otherwise one can leverage nonuniform vertex degrees to (usually) significantly decrease the search space of vertex permutations.

so the best route to studying known hard scientific problems is to relate your own approach to the literature aka *"terra cognita"*, which is quite large on this subject. for problems this significant, most straightforward approaches are attempted/ analyzed "somewhere". Here are some fairly close references to your technique, they share many close similarities. & then the task is to try to determine how your technique is different. Your basic idea of assigning columns/ rows of the adjacency matrix to different matrices is basically a partitioning algorithm of vertices into different sets. so:

- [complexity of open partitions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96858/complexity-of-equitable-partitions) / open question by McKay on mathoverflow. he asks about the complexity of partitioning regular graphs into vertex partitions with the "equitability" property that may be similar to yours. he is the writer of [nauty](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml) the top software for graph isomorphism computations.
- [Efficient graph automorphism by vertex partitioning](http://haralick.org/journals/graph_automorphism_vertex_partitioning.pdf) / Fowler et al. from abstract, an algorithm that runs in P time for all graphs tested including regular graphs.

My suggestion is also to try to convert your problem to isomorphism instances and empirically test nauty on it (just as the 1st paper uses empirical testing, which is accepted with conditions in this area), and that may be one of the more efficient known approaches, because nauty encodes vast swathes of state-of-the-art knowledge/ algorithm(s) on graph isomorphism complexity study.

Comment: thanks, for your precious time, but this is a suggestion post rather than an answer, thanks anyway.btw, it is a direct question.

Comment: good luck! your _research effort_ seems un- or dis-connected from the CS/ math literature to me which goes against scientific convention... think many votes are for your latex/ analysis skills...

Comment: addendum, further analysis/ discussion in this [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/25373/room-for-jim-and-vzn). feel the question is more about a subroutine in a graph isomorphism algorithm. another similar paper [AN ALGORITHM FOR DETERMINING ISOMORPHISM USING LEXICOGRAPHIC SORTING AND THE MATRIX INVERSE](http://www.usafa.edu/df/dfe/dfer/centers/accr/docs/augeri2007b.pdf) / Augeri et al has concept of "canonical isomorphs" in section 2.1.3.

Comment: I read the paper but failed to see any similarity.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed Solution:**

Arrangement of $G$: $A$ is the matrix of graph $G$ where $|G|=|A|=n$. Based on the adjacency of last vertex($n$ th vertex), A can be divided in to 4 sub-matrices where 2 are symmetric matrices($C,D$) and 2 are non square matrices($E^{T}, E$). One symmetric matrix, say, $D$ , has size $<n/2$. Repeat the whole procedure for matrix $D$ and  $k$ th vertex  $; 0<k<n$.
   This procedure can be done maximum $log_2(n)$ times.

Description of the Algorithm:***$A,B$ are symmetric matrices of graphs $G,H$ respectively.*** For $x \in G$,consider the graph $(G-x)$, it has vertices adjacent to $x$ and vertices  non adjacent to $x$.

$ A_x$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph $(G-x)$, where $C$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph created by  vertices  of $(G-x)$ which are  adjacent to $x$ and $D$ is the symmetric matrix of the  graph  created by  vertices  of $(G-x)$ which are  not  adjacent to $x$.

$ A_x =  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
C & E \\
E^{T} & D\\
 \end{array} \right)$

It should be noted, that-

  1. Interchanging/swapping any two rows(or columns) of $C$ does not affect matrix $D$ (and vice versa) .
2. Any change in $C$ or $D$ or  both $C$ and $D$ changes matrix $E$.

If $G \simeq H $ then there exists $u \in H$ so that, $(G-x)\simeq (H-u)$, the matrix of $(H-u)$ is $B_u$, where$ B_u= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
S & R \\
R^{T} & Q\\
 \end{array} \right) $

Consider the situation where $S \neq C,D \neq Q$. Since  $(G-x)\simeq (H-u)$ ,so,  there exists a permutation matrix $P$ ,so that $PQ=D$.
 Once $Q$ is arranged exactly like $D$ then $C$ can be arranged in non-exponential  time **using the arrangement of rows of $E$ because after $Q=D$, the rows of $E$ and $R$ would be same but arranged in different order. For example, 1st row may be placed in 4th row, but 1st row will look same in 4th row, here only order is changed(1st to 4th).**

[ Once Q is arranged exactly like D, you can not change / reorder/ permute  vertices which made Q, because if you change / reorder / permute vertices of Q, then Q will not be equal to  D.If you can not change Q(=D), then there will be no column change in R(which is expected equal to E) as changing any column in R will change Q( but not S). So , after, Q is arranged exactly like D, change can be done  in S matrix, if you change S, then only rows of E  will change their order].

So, arrange the order   of rows of $R$ like $E$, it will make $S = C$.