# Dependency of submatrix used in a combinatorial strategy .

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, solution-verification, extremal-combinatorics

***This is a verification post , Please inform if anything is undefined or unclear or miss-tagged. Also if you vote up/down it would be helpfull if you leave a comment.***

**Introduction:**
Given a matrix A of a  $k$ regular graph G. The matrix A can be divided into 4 sub matrices  based on adjacency of vertex $x \in G$.
 $A_x$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph $(G-x)$, where $C$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph created by  vertices of $(G-x)$ which are  adjacent to $x$ and $D$ is the symmetric matrix of the graph created by  vertices of $(G-x)$ which are not adjacent to $x$. For example,

$$ A_x = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc|ccc|c}
0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
\hline
1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
C & E & 0 \\
E^{T} & D & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array} \right) 
$$

It should be noted that

1. Interchanging/swapping any two rows (or columns) of $C$ does not affect matrix $D$ (and vice versa).
2. Any change in $C$ or $D$ or both $C$ and $D$ changes matrix $E$.

If some vertices of $G$ is rearranged (i.e., permuted), $A$  will be different, say, ***this new matrix is $B$. Again, matrix $B$ can be divided into 4 sub matrices  based on adjacency of vertex $x \in G$ and $ B_x$ can be obtained.***
$ B_x= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
S & R \\
R^{T} & Q\\
 \end{array} \right) $

**Given:** Both matrices $A,B$ are divided  based on same vertex $x$, and $D=Q$ (so that $A_x=B_x $ happens, because for all  $D=Q$,$A_x=B_x $  may not happen ).

**Claim:**  Since $D=Q$, To get $A=B$, only $S$ matrix needs to be reordered(so that $S=C$ which will imply $A=B$) . ***To get $A=B$, so there will be no change/permutation/ swapping  in columns of $R$ to get $E=R$.***

**Question:**  Is this claim  correct?
This question is related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336344/reorder-adjacency-matrices-of-regular-graphs-so-they-are-the-same).

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**  Because any change in matrix $S$, will reorder the rows of $R$ only. Once Q is arranged exactly like D, you can not change / reorder/ permute  vertices which made Q, because if you change / reorder / permute vertices of Q, then Q will not be equal to  D.If you can not change Q(=D), then there will be no column change in R(which is expected equal to E) as changing any column in R will change Q( but not S). So , after, Q is arranged exactly like D, change can be done  in S matrix, if you change S, then only rows of E  will change their order.